# How to route different db requests to read only instance

Tags: entity-framework, replication, readonly

We have our primary database in Europe, and it is replicated using azure to a closer region as a readonly instance. This costs us quite a lot every month and we are only using it to he able to fail over in a disaster situation. We are also limited in sql scaling, as we have to scale both instances, even thoguh the readonly instance sits and does nothing..

However is there not a way we can intelligently use it for read queries? So I want to somehow make a read only db context and it's it's reading, use the close db.

Comment: Use two data sources, one for each one. Use the secondary one for SELECT queries such as reporting. This is the same strategy of Aurora database at AWS. You have two endpoints: one for normal read-write, and the secondary one for read-only. Your app needs to set two connections separately and decide which connection to use per query. This is not automatic.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't really related to the <sql> _language_.)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SQL or Entity Framework. I think you should remove irrelevant tags and add tags that explicitly indicate the technologies used.

Comment: Look at [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview), [Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to have a MyDbContext and a MyDbContextReadOnly, each configured with an appropriate connection string.

One can be a subclass of the other, or they can both be subclasses of a common custom DbContext.